# VB6 Winsock Error Invalid Argument 10014

Tags: vb6, winsock

```
Private Sub Form_Load()
    Winsock1.RemotePort = 22222
    Winsock1.Protocol = sckUDPProtocol
End Sub

Private Sub Command1_Click()
    Command1.Enabled = False

    Dim sendBuff As String

    sendBuff = "XXXXX"

    Label1:

    On Error GoTo Label2
    Winsock1.RemoteHost = "andon-eds-1"
    Winsock1.SendData sendBuff

    Label2:

    Winsock1.Close
    Winsock1.Protocol = sckUDPProtocol
    Winsock1.RemotePort = 22222
    Winsock1.LocalPort = 0   

Label3:

    On Error GoTo EndOfSub
    Winsock1.RemoteHost = "andon-eds-1"
    Winsock1.SendData sendBuff


EndOfSub:
Command1.Enabled = True
End Sub

Private Sub Command2_Click()
Command2.Enabled = False

On Error GoTo EndOfSub
    Winsock1.RemoteHost = "andon-eds-1"
    Winsock1.SendData "XXXXX"
EndOfSub:

Command2.Enabled = True
End Sub

Private Sub Command3_Click()
On Error Resume Next
    Command3.Enabled = False

    Dim sendBuff As String

    sendBuff = "XXXXX"

    PrintWinsockProperty

    Winsock1.RemoteHost = "andon-eds-1"
    Winsock1.SendData sendBuff

    PrintWinsockProperty

    Winsock1.Close
    Winsock1.Protocol = sckUDPProtocol
    Winsock1.RemotePort = 22222
    Winsock1.LocalPort = 0    

    PrintWinsockProperty

    Winsock1.RemoteHost = "andon-eds-1"
    Winsock1.SendData sendBuff

    PrintWinsockProperty

    Command3.Enabled = True
End Sub
```

'the host name "andon-eds-1" is not online and i want my application can continues

1. when i click Command1 i found an error Invalid Argument : 10014 
   at >>Winsock1.SendData sendBuff << below Label3 my application cannot continues
2. when i click Command2 2 times it can continues without application close
3. when i click Command3 it can continues without application close
   my question are what's the difference between 1.) and 2.) ? and
   what's difference between On Error Resume Next and On Error GoTo for my problem ?

   (** i'm sorry about my english skills)
   thanks

   ```
   Private Sub Command6_Click()

       Dim i As Integer

       Command6.Enabled = False

       On Error GoTo BeginLoop
       Winsock1.RemoteHost = "Andon-eds-1"
       Winsock1.SendData "XXXXX"

   BeginLoop:

       Resume Next
       For i = 0 To 2
           Winsock1.RemoteHost = "Andon-eds-" & i
           Winsock1.SendData "XXXXX"

           Debug.Print Err.Number '0 '0 '0
       Next

       On Error GoTo TestLabel
           i = 100 / 0

       Command6.Enabled = True
       Exit Sub

   TestLabel:

   End Sub
   ```

Comment: Try showing us which lines the errors occur on.

Comment: "Winsock1.SendData sendBuff" in Command1_Click below the Label3

Comment: Can you try to explain more about what you are trying to do with the code you have provided?

Comment: I'm supposed to have 4 PCs, 1st PC is running this program. 3 PCs running client program. and 1 of 3 PCs is offline when the 1st PC send message to the clients it has an error and application was closed. I want the program on 1st PC can continues without closing.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you are trying to do with the code so I can't answer your entire question but I can answer this part of your question:

> What's the difference between On Error Resume Next and On Error GoTo.

Resume next will cause execution to go on to the next line of code if an error happens. For On Error GoTo, that will take your code to the label specified after the GoTo in the section of code that follows the On Error GoTo.

Answer (score 0):

[Error 10014 (WSAEFAULT) is Bad Address](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms740668%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

The system detected an invalid pointer address in attempting to use a pointer argument of a call. This error occurs if an application passes an invalid pointer value, or if the length of the buffer is too small. For instance, if the length of an argument, which is a sockaddr structure, is smaller than the sizeof(sockaddr).

Check that the machine `"andon-eds-1"` can be pinged ok

Comment: it's offline but i want my application can continues

Comment: In that case you just need to handle the error in whichever way you would like - have a look at [this link](http://www.vb6.us/tutorials/error-handling) to get you started